# How to make presentation more visual when the subject is mathematical?

Tags: presentation, defense

My defense is soon. I want to make the presentation engaging and visual but the topic is very mathematical. What can I do?

Comment: Can you give some additional details, most importantly is this a PhD defense or, say, MSc defense? The answers will certainly depend on the level, discipline, topic, and country/culture. For example, if this is a PhD defense in mathematics in front of a small committee of mathematicians, I'd say you focus on the content, not the visualization. If it is a public defense in, say, sociology in front of a varied audience, then it is another matter.

Comment: @lemon314 It is a Phd defense in electrical and computer engineering, but my topic is related to asymptotic analysis of certain classifiers so it is very statistical and involves a lot of mathematical derivation. It is open to a public audience.

Comment: Did you already ask your advisor? What did they suggest? By the way, many math topics are quite visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question still seems very broad - how to present own research during a defense in an engaging way - and as such, I feel, it's hard to give a helpful answer, especially when the defense is looming (and I expect a question "how do I illustrate such-and-such asymptotic analysis" would be off-topic here). On the other hand, I do have a bit of general advice that may help here, so I post this instead of a comment. From your question it is unclear, whether you have no experience in visualization/providing intuition for mathematics, or no experience in typesetting mathematics (i.e. LaTeX and such), so I'll assume neither.

First and foremost, **consult colleagues in your institution** (and your supervisor as well) what sort of presentation is expected of you. This is the country/culture-dependence I mentioned in the comments. Most importantly, it may turn out that you'd unnecessarily spend time producing graphs/animations/pictures/LaTeX figures, when the committee will be more interested in, say, asking about passages from your thesis, each one with a printed copy on them. I most certainly share the conviction that mathematics can and should be presented in a visually pleasing way, but learning how to do that (both in general and for a particular application) simply takes time that you might or might not have right before your defense.

Second, your colleagues may also provide guidance, whether your committee actually expects visual (or other) explanation of the mathematical background, or if they are likely to consider it superfluous (I attended a defense in sociology, enjoyed careful explanation of maths behind models used, and at one point someone said "why are you taking so much time on this stuff, let's get to the good bit"). Without knowing the expectations at your institution it is very hard to give good advice here. And also, as this is a defense, I wouldn't want the advice to backfire: for example, there is a very common framing device of [Alice and Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) in quantum/cryptography talks (I'd use it myself, with pictures, especially if I wasn't sure everyone is fluent in underlying maths), **but** I personally know a mathematician who got offended the first time they heard a speaker using Alice and Bob, as they (quite wrongly) assumed the speaker was being childish and condescending towards them. Again, talk to people at your faculty and ask them what sort of presentations they used or seen used during the defenses that went well. If your thesis is sufficiently different in content and uses much more mathematics - reach out to mathematicians in your institution and ask them instead.

That being said, as I don't want to be unhelpful and too negative, I can at least give you some additional directions. You may want to check [SE for Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) for some pointers towards examples/tools/good practices for visualizing maths (although I suspect "how do I illustrate such-and-such asymptotic analysis" would be off-topic there as well). Finally, if you are asking more about typesetting a readable presentation with mathematical content, I would encourage you to take a look at the LaTeX templates provided to/by [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates), as they might give you some ideas how to squeeze long figures into readable slides with Beamer.

Good luck with your defense:)